# When Container::clearResolvedInstance should be used

Tags: laravel

Out of curiosity, I'd like to know why Http/Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter($request) sets an instance of request and immediately right after wipes it out.

```
protected function sendRequestThroughRouter($request)
{
    $this->app->instance('request', $request);

    Facade::clearResolvedInstance('request');
...
```

What is the purpose of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I finally got the point:

- Facades just hold references to the actual service instances located in the Container
- If the instance is replaced by a new instance via $app->instance() or by other means, then the Facade reference becomes obsolete since it is still pointing to the previous deleted instance
- By clearing the facade instance reference with clearResolvedInstance, it forces the facade to store a new reference the next time the facade is invoked via resolveFacadeInstance($name)

Did I get it right?

This leads to another question:

What's the point of managing and returning these resolvedInstances:

```
if (isset(static::$resolvedInstance[$name])) {
        return static::$resolvedInstance[$name];
    }

return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
```

Instead of just always return the instance directly from Container like this:

```
return static::$app[$name];
```

Answer (score 0):

because it is registerd app wide

```
/**
     * Register an existing instance as shared in the container.
     *
     * @param  string  $abstract
     * @param  mixed   $instance
     * @return void
     */
    public function instance($abstract, $instance);
```

after it is registered in the container then unresolved version is wiped as far as I am understanding

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain a little more? you mention that the "unresolved version is wiped", curiously  the method is called "clearResolvedInstance". Please try to elaborate your answer a little more. Thanks,

Comment: I am not a pro... https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container check this link especially binding instances part which clearly states that an existing object is passed to container which is resolution I guess... so what it is doing is getting raw HTTP request and binding it to  app container so that further down one would be able to use say $request->has('some_thing') ...

Comment: 1.- You bind request object to container. I got that. So what exactly Facade::clearResolvedInstance('request') does ? Which instance clears out?